# Maintain Sprite position relative to frame/screen when auto-scaling from iphone 5 to 6?

Tags: ios, sprite, positioning, scaling

I've developed a game in SpriteKit for a 5s. All my sprites are positioned just where I want them when I run the Xcode simulator on a 4s, 5 or 5s:

http://tinypic.com/r/f0yanl/8

But when I run it on a 6 my sprites are not positioned correctly, and some are even placed off the entire frame/screen:

http://tinypic.com/r/akdac7/8

Notice my HUD is showing up top out of the frame, and the shadow and positioning of my "Machine" at the bottom is off, etc.

Is there a quick, simple fix to ensure the sprites maintain their position relative to my background image, when running on a 6? For now, I'm OK with the entire screen being collapsed a bit when running on a 6 (with empty borders on all four sides), but I would like to make sure everything at least looks just as clean and in order as it does on a 5.

I've used anchor points for most of my nodes, for e.g.:

```
+ (instancetype) machineAtPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    GameMachineNode *machine = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"machine_1"];
    machine.position = position;
    machine.name = @"Machine"; 
    machine.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);

....

}
```

My "GameViewController.m" includes a resize to fill mode:

```
SKScene * scene = [GameTitleScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: figured it out. Was as simple as adding this single line of code to the initWithSize method:

background.size = self.frame.size;

Full code block for reference:

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

```
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = 0; //initializing this property
    self.timeSinceEnemyAdded = 0; //initializing this property
    self.addEnemyTimeInterval = 1.25;
    self.totalGameTime = 0;
    self.minSpeed = GameAstroDogMinSpeed;
    self.restart = NO;
    self.gameOver = NO;
    self.gameOverDisplayed = NO;

    // Setup your scene here....

    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background_1"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    background.size = self.frame.size;
```